# Aurelia custom gulp watcher

Tags: node.js, gulp, aurelia

Trying to get a custom watcher to work:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    shell = require('gulp-shell');

gulp.task('run-au', shell.task(['au build']));

gulp.task('build', gulp.series('run-au', () => {
   return gulp.src('./wwwroot/**/*.*')
               .pipe(gulp.dest('../Something.Api/wwwroot'));
}));

gulp.task('watch', () => {
    gulp.watch('./src/**/*.*').on('change', gulp.series('build'));
});
```

Pretty straightforward, it works when I change something in `src`, but when it detects that change, it goes into a cyclic build cycle, where it will keep on running `build`

### Additions

I saw that `environment.js` seemed to be getting updated which could have affected the watch thus creating the cyclic build, however even changing to:

```
gulp.task('watch', () => {
    gulp.watch(['./src/**/*.*', '!./src/env*.*']).on('change', gulp.series('build'));
});
```

Didn't seem to change the outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the docs it states:

> ### gulp.watch(globs[, opts][, fn])
>
> #### opts
>
> Type: `Object`
>
> `queue` (boolean, default: `true`). Whether or not a file change should queue the fn execution if the fn is already running. Useful for a long running fn.

So I added:

```
gulp.task('watch', () => {
    gulp.watch(['./src/**/*.*', '!./src/env*.*'], {queue: false}, gulp.series('build'));
});
```